# Running a cron job 3 times (1 pm, 2 pm and 3 pm for example)?

Tags: cron

I am not sure how to run a cron job at 3 specific hours every day. I want to run it at 1pm, 2 pm and 3pm.

Is it possible, using a single expression?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

you may use this:

```
# m   h   dom mon dow   command
0 13,14,15 *   *   *     /home/user/command
```

your `/home/user/command` will be run at 13:00, 14:00 and 15:00

Comment: @user1856596 sure thing! don't forget to replace leading `*` with `0`

Answer (score 11):

As lenik stated, it can be done in single expression.

```
0 13,14,15 * * * <your-script-to-run>
```

Check [this geedkstuff link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) for more examples

Comment: leading star will run this every minute =)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very useful.

Answer (score 9):

While the given answers are correct, an unexperienced user might not know where to put this expression. You have to edit the `crontab` file, like:

```
crontab -e
```

There you add

```
0 13,14,15 *   *   *     /home/user/command
```

to execute your command at 13:00, 14:00 and 15:00. Also note that `user` has to be substituted with the user account the command is executed in.

Comment: please, don't touch system-wide `/etc/crontab`, use `crontab -e` instead to edit _your own_ cron table.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following as well:

```
0 13-15 * * * /home/apps/sample.sh
```

Comment: backslashes should be slashes, but the range is a good suggestion

Answer (score 2):

To anyone landing here --> useful tool:

> https://crontab.guru/

Please prefer range+step over commas:

```
Example: Run every 2h from 9h to 16h
m    h     dom mon dow   command
0  9-16/2   *   *   *     /home/user/command
```

Also applicable to minutes:

```
    m        h     dom mon dow   command
10-30/10  9-16/2   *   *   *     /home/user/command
```

**Crontab guru** shows what it means, and the next scheduled jobs.

For example I typed this cron at 10h05:

[image]