# Cron Expression to execute cron triggers for given times with hour and minute

Tags: java, triggers, cron, quartz-scheduler

Here is 
[a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584699/running-a-cron-job-3-times-1-pm-2-pm-and-3-pm-for-example)

. I want to run Quarta schduler at 1.00pm, 2.10pm, 5.15pm. That means Hour+minute. Any one help me with Cron expression for this plz ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do as exactly as you specified. As you mentioned in the question, [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) [are](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) some resources, which help you overcome this (Not as exactly as your requirement). But if you can change your **minute** time to a same number you can achieve this easily. If the **minute** number is so important you have to run 3 triggers. That seems to be the easiest way. It has mentioned in [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06).

> Note that some scheduling requirements are too complicated to express with a single trigger - such as "every 5 minutes between 9:00 am and 10:00 am, and every 20 minutes between 1:00 pm and 10:00 pm". The solution in this scenario is to simply create two triggers, and register both of them to run the same job.

Comment: Thank you Maleenc. as you say, it is easy if all the minutes are same. I add an expression like 0 00,10,15 13,14,17 .. scheduler ran for 00,10,15 minutes each given hour.

Comment: Aash, Were you able find a solution? If so please share an answer. Otherwise you can rate my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use three lines like this:

```
0 13 * * * /bin/Quarta
10 14 * * * /bin/Quarta
15 17 * * * /bin/Quarta
```

Or whatever command you need to get it running. Might be worth making the command a shell script so you only have to modify the parameters in one place.