# Setting a cron job for 3 specific times in a day?

Tags: cron

I understand how to do one every hour or every hour in 3 hours, but how do I set a cron job for 3 different specific times? Namely: 07:15, 16:30, 23:00.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a cron job 3 times (1 pm, 2 pm and 3 pm for example)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584699/running-a-cron-job-3-times-1-pm-2-pm-and-3-pm-for-example)

Comment: @aberna I saw that, is the first column then something like 15,30,00? Wouldn't that make the job run at 7:30 and 7:00 as well?

Comment: I realized now what you are looking for. Any reason to compress everything in one line of the crontab ?

Comment: @aberna yes, it's a splunk limitation

Answer (score 2):

By adding three lines like this.

07:15

```
15 7 * * * <command>
```

16:30

```
30 16 * * * <command>
```

23:00

```
0 23 * * * <command>
```

---

This is the definition:

```
,----------------- minute (0-59)
| ,--------------- hour (0-23)
| | ,------------- day of month (1-31)
| | | ,----------- month (1-12) or use names
| | | | ,--------- day of week (0-7) (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
| | | | |
* * * * * <command>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can only do it on one line due to limitations on splunk. But have an upvote anyway!

Comment: Could you figure out how to do it in one line? Need similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule more than once in a single cron

“At minute 15 past hour 7, 16, and 23.”

`15 07,16,23 * * *`

Reference
https://crontab.guru/#15_07,16,23_*_*_*