# Python: execute command at certain (flexible) time

Tags: python, loops, time

I am trying to make a python script execute two commands at specific times. Usually I would just use cron, but the commands need to be executed at different times each day.

So far, I have created a while loop running a time checking function over and over again:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime     
import time         

x = -1 # for loop

def Zeitcheck():
   currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M') 


   if currentTime == time1:
       # command to run goes here
       time.sleep(55)
       return

   elif currentTime == time2:
       # command to run goes here
       time.sleep(55)
       return

   else:
       print currentTime
       time.sleep(55)
       return

while x == -1:
Zeitcheck()
```

(the values from time1 and time2 come from an external file)

The script works, but this time loop does not seem to be the best way to handle this. Is there a more elegant solution? Thanks!

Comment: FYI You can run cron at different times in a day like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584699/running-a-cron-job-3-times-1-pm-2-pm-and-3-pm-for-example

Comment: The times to run those commands change daily. So if I used cron, I would have to edit cron each day as well.

Comment: Run the script every 5 minutes and check inside the script if it is the time to run.

Comment: Does time1 and time2 changes? If they do, how often?

Comment: Wrap each command in a  script which reads the time to execute the command: step 1: if it is time, execute the command and go to step 2; otherwise, goto step 2; step 2: schedule the script to re-execute at the required time using `at`. Just a thought...

Comment: Take a look at this lib : https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: @Ben: what is wrong with [editing `crontab` every day using a Python script](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)? (each program does what it is good at: python script finds when to run the commands, `cron` is responsible for running -- it can simplify your main python script and makes the solution more robust). `cron` can run the main Python script every day, to schedule other commands for the day.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Looks like that could be a good option for me. The schedule script looks good too. I will try both and see what works better for me :)