# AWS Glue Crawler - Scheduling crawler run three times a day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue Crawler. I want to run this crawler three times a day . I have few questions on same:

I want to run Crawler three times a day 6 AM, 2 PM, 10 PM UTC. What should be the cron expression for same ?

Update : This below cron expression works perfectly fine.

```
cron(0 6,14,22 * * ? *)
```

Comment: can you try with this cron : 0 6,14,22 * * *   refer this : https://crontab.tech/3-times-a-day and also this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584699/running-a-cron-job-3-times-1-pm-2-pm-and-3-pm-for-example/13584807

Comment: This does not work, since AWS has a different syntax.

Comment: Bokambo, what does not work here?

Comment: My above expression works perfectly fine, there was a space in the end which was causing the issue. Thanks for all the suggestions and help.